# Using a python program to rename all XML files within a linux directory

Tags: python, xml, linux, rename

Currently, my code uses the name of an XML file as a parameter in order to take that file, parse some of its content and use it to rename said file, what I mean to do is actually run my program once and that program will search for every XML file (even if its inside a zip) inside the directory and rename it using the same parameters which is what I am having problems with.

```
#encoding:utf-8
import os, re
from sys import argv

script, nombre_de_archivo = argv

regexFecha = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
regexLocalidad = r'localidad=\"[\w\s.,-_]*\"'
regexNombre = r'nombre=\"[\w\s.,-_]*\"'
regexTotal = r'total=\"\d+.?\d+\"'

fechas = []; localidades = []; nombres = []; totales = []

archivo = open(nombre_de_archivo)

for linea in archivo.readlines():
    fechas.append(re.findall(regexFecha, linea))
    localidades.append(re.findall(regexLocalidad, linea))
    nombres.append(re.findall(regexNombre, linea))
    totales.append(re.findall(regexTotal, linea))

fecha = str(fechas[1][0])
localidad = str(localidades[1][0]).strip('localidad=\"')
nombre = str(nombres[1][0]).strip('nombre=\"')
total = str(totales[1][0]).strip('total=\"')

nombre_nuevo_archivo = fecha+"_"+localidad+"_"+nombre+"_"+total+".xml"

os.rename(nombre_de_archivo, nombre_nuevo_archivo)
```

EDIT: an example of this would be.

directory contains only 3 files as well as the program.

silly.xml amusing.zip feisty.txt

So, you run the program and it ignores feisty as it is a .txt file and it reads silly.xml, ti then parses "fechas, localidad, nombre, total" concatenate or append or whatever and use that as the new file for silly.xml, then the program checks if zip has an xml file, if it does then it does the same thing.

so in the end we would have

20141211_sonora_walmart_2033.xml 20141008_sonora_starbucks_102.xml feisty txt amusing.zip

Comment: It makes sense if you show your input (a list of filenames) and your expected output (modified filenames).

Comment: You need to `close` the opened files also.

Comment: I edited something of the sort as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear, and the code you posted is too broad.

I can't debug regular expressions with the power of my sight, but there's a number of things you can do to simplify the code. Simple code means less errors, and an easier time debugging.

To locate your target files, use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
files = glob.glob('dir/*.xml')
```

To parse them, ditch regular expressions and use the [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) API.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('target.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

There's also modules to navigate XML files with CSS notation and XPATH. Extracting fields form the filename using regex is okay, but check out [named groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Element Tree trimmed a lot of fat out of the code, excellent answer.
glob.glob worked wonders.